# Running python in background on PHP page wait for responce

Tags: php, python, cmd, sendmail

[running process in background on hangs PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881180/running-process-in-background-on-hangs-php-page)

I did as explained in this above link but it did not work.

Question:

I want to send mail using Python from PHP. When I call Python, my page waits for a response from Python. I want to run Python in the background.

I also redirect Python's response to another location ex: `"E:\\nil.txt"`, but it still waits for a response.

I am working on Windows 7. My problem is that all the answers I could find were for Linux.

My PHP code:

```
    public static function callPython($scriptName, $data){
      $path = "C:\\Users\\Aditya\\Desktop\\".$scriptName.".py";
  //$data=array("to"=>$to,"name"=>$name,"headingSection"=>$headingSection,"body"=>$body,"subject"=>$subject);
     $jsonArray = json_encode($data);
     $jsonArray = str_replace('"', '\"', $jsonArray);
     $dir= "E:\\nil.txt";
     $cmd = 'python '.$path.' '.$jsonArray.' >'.$dir.' 2>&1 &';
     var_dump($cmd);
     shell_exec($cmd);
   }
```

If you need my Python script, then I will post it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the main thing is how the python file is getting executed from the php code you have written? it is only loading the file in the $path file. and how are you getting the $data while it is not having anything as you are not storing any.

hope you get my point.

i will give you an idea.

When the php  file is calling the python file. the python file should execute like we do in cmd. python some.py like this. then whatever is returned should be loaded in your php function to see it.

hope it helps

Comment: it works perfect expect it always give responce to php. Although my problem solved in linux. Also i want to konw solution for windows. thnkx for ur respond

Comment: you asked for that only ? to get the response to the php file.

you want to get the response in python file??

Comment: i even don't want response....but as my python give response and php wait for it. All i want to just call python and php forget about getting response or any other

Comment: ok so use a exit command in the php file so that you dont need to wait for the response. and the python file will work in the background..

:) cheers

Comment: yup ..

see when you dont want anything except the python code to run in the background kill the php process. thats it

Comment: thnkx...i will try it